# Control the convex combination of two classes on the boundary of the kahler cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(X,w)$ be a compact kahler manifold, and $[\eta]$ be a class is on the boundary of the kahler cone. The claim is that one can find another class $[\beta]$ also on the boundary of the kahler cone such that $(1-t)[\beta] + t[\eta] > 0$ when $t \in (0, 1)$. How can one prove this?

Some thoughts:
according to  [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19632/question-about-kahler-cone-of-a-compact-kahler-manifold), one reasonable way to prove the claim is to find some $k < 0$ such that $[w] + k[\eta]$ not kahler. Then there is some chance for this choice to be on the boundary of the cone. Now consider $(1-t)([w] + k[\eta]) + t[\eta] = (1-t)[w] + (k + (1-k)t)[\eta]$. If $(k + (1-k)t)$ is positive then the resulting sum will be kahler. However, how can one gaurantee that 1).$[w] + k[\eta]$ is on the boundary of the cone  2). $(k + (1-k)t) > 0$?

Comment: This is false if $[\eta]=0$, which is definitely on the boundary of the Kahler cone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $[\eta]$ is on the boundary of the Kähler cone and that $[\eta] \neq 0.$

Define $k := -\sup\{t > 0 : [\omega]-t[\eta] \hskip4pt {\rm Kähler}\}$.  We claim that $k > -\infty$.

If $k = -\infty,$ then $\frac{1}{t}[\omega]-[\eta]$ is Kähler for all $t > 0,$ so that $-[\eta]$ is nef.  The claim will be proved once we show this implies $[\eta]=0.$

**Approach 1, suggested by @YangMills in the comments below:**

By weak compactness of currents, nef classes are pseudoeffective, i.e. they contain closed positive currents. So there are distributions $,$ such that $\eta+^{c} \geq 0$ and $−{\eta}+^{c}v \geq 0$. So $^{}(+) \geq 0$ i.e. $+$ is plurisubharmonic, hence constant. Thus $\eta$ and $-{\eta}$ differ by $^{}$ of a distribution, which must be smooth by regularity of $^{}$. So $[\eta]$ and $-[\eta]$ are cohomologous, hence $[\eta]=0.$

**Approach 2, admittedly overkill but of a more algebro-geometric flavor:**

Since both $[\eta]$ and $[-\eta]$ are nef, it follows from the characterization of nefness given as part (iii) of Theorem 4.3 in the Demailly-Paun paper

https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v159-n3-p05.pdf

that for every Kähler class ${\omega}'$ on $X$ we have $$\int_{X}\eta~ \wedge ({\omega}')^{\dim(X)-1} = 0$$
By nondegeneracy we must then have $[\eta]=0.$

We then have that $k > -\infty$ as claimed.

It is clear that $[\omega]+k[\eta]$ lies on the boundary of the Kähler cone.  In order to show that $$(1−)([\omega]+[])+[] = (1−)[\omega]+(+(1−))[]$$ is Kähler for all $t \in (0,1)$ it is enough to verify that 
$$\frac{k+(1-k)t}{1-t} > k$$ for all $t \in (0,1),$ which is straightforward.

Comment: This doesn't work when $[\eta]=0$, in which case you get $k=-\infty$

Comment: Thanks--I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Your argument is still incomplete, since you did not show that $k>-\infty$. Here is the proof: if we had $k=-\infty$ then by definition $-[\eta]+\frac{1}{t}[\omega]$ is Kahler for all $t>0$, and so $-[\eta]$ is a limit of Kahler classes, i.e. $-[\eta]$ is nef. But you can easily see that if both $[\eta]$ and $-[\eta]$ are nef, then necessarily $[\eta]=0$.

Comment: I have incorporated this into the answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need the Demailly-Paun (rather difficult) theorem! By weak compactness of currents, nef classes are pseudoeffective, i.e. they contain closed positive currents. So there are distributions $u,v$ such that $\eta+dd^c u\geq 0$ and $-\eta+dd^c v\geq 0$. So $dd^c(u+v)\geq 0$ i.e. $u+v$ is plurisubharmonic, hence constant. Thus $\eta$ and $-\eta$ differ by $dd^c$ of a distribution, which must be smooth by regularity of $dd^c$. So $\eta$ and $-\eta$ are cohomologous, hence $[\eta]=0$.